# Is it possible to use arrow keys alone to expand tree node in package explorer in Eclipse on Linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

When using Eclipse I browse through the package explorer tree using the keyboard arrows a lot.

In Windows I can expand a collapsed node by pressing the <kbd>→</kbd> key. In Linux I need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>. Is there a way to reconfigure this so that <kbd>Shift</kbd> is not required?

Comment: This really isn't an Eclipse question. Eclipse uses native OS widgets, like tree controls and key binding behavior that you are describing comes from windows. I am adding windows tag to your question.

Comment: @Konstantin fair point, but wouldn't linux or even ubuntu (to be specific) be a better tag as that's where I'm having the problem, not in windows.

Comment: good point. swapping windows tag for linux.

Comment: It would be nice to imitate the Windows behaviour even closer: `Right` on an already expanded node should jump to the first child, `Left` on an already collapsed node should jump to its parent node.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My version for GTK3 that behaves in more natural way.
Add the following to ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css:

```
@binding-set MyTreeViewBinding
{
    bind "Left"     { "select-cursor-parent" ()
                      "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,0,0) };
    bind "Right"    { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,1,0) };
}

GtkTreeView
{
    gtk-key-bindings: MyTreeViewBinding;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion, the answer would be more helpful if you explicitly described how this behaves differently.

Comment: Excellent. I adapted the css to use shift+left instead. [Check it out](https://gist.github.com/mppfiles/1c541ec9bd90e655aab28ade4c0ce21f).

Comment: Changed the accepted answer to this one as I guess most are using GTK3 by now

Answer (score 113):

Put this into your `~/.gtkrc-2.0` and you should be good to go.  The Left and Right lines make the requested change, the rest are just my personal additions to make the tree-view act more vim-like.

```
binding "gtk-binding-tree-view" {
    bind "j"        { "move-cursor" (display-lines, 1) }
    bind "k"        { "move-cursor" (display-lines, -1) }
    bind "h"        { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (1,0,0) }
    bind "l"        { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (1,1,0) }
    bind "o"        { "move-cursor" (pages, 1) }
    bind "u"        { "move-cursor" (pages, -1) }
    bind "g"        { "move-cursor" (buffer-ends, -1) }
    bind "y"        { "move-cursor" (buffer-ends, 1) }
    bind "p"        { "select-cursor-parent" () }
    bind "Left"     { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,0,0) }
    bind "Right"    { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,1,0) }
    bind "semicolon" { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,1,1) }
    bind "slash"    { "start-interactive-search" () }
}
class "GtkTreeView" binding "gtk-binding-tree-view"
```

then restart your Eclipse to apply new bindings

Comment: I want to hug you so hard. This has bugged me for months!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem when I was using Ubuntu + gnome. I now switched to Fluxbox and the issue is back, any suggestion?

Comment: It works indeed great when the current selection is on a folder. But the left arrow behavior is still not exactly the same as on Windows. On an already collapsed folder, it would bring you to the parent folder. Also, when the current selection is a file, it would bring you to the parent folder. However on Mint it still stays in the current selection. But this is still a huge improvement, thanks!

Comment: This was working great until Eclipse Luna, any ideas why stopped working?

Comment: This works for Eclipse Juno and Kepler, but doesn't work for Luna!

Comment: @akapelko one guess I have is that Luna uses a newer version of GTK than 2.0 so maybe the contents need to be placed in a file with a larger version number?  Consider using strace on the process to see where it's looking

Comment: Luna: use "big data nerd"'s answer (see below)

Comment: Adding `bind "<Alt>Up" { "select-cursor-parent" () }` will enable you to use Alt-Up to jump to the parent node. Then you can easily collapse the tree, even if you current child-node selection is far down the list.

Comment: how to do this in Kubuntu? I do not have gnome in use and therefor I have not found a file that looks similar to what you show here in my user home

Comment: @akapelko You can deactivate GTK 3 (and thereby falling back to GTK 2) using this: 
export SWT_GTK3=0

Comment: Works perfectly for GnuCash too - thank you! Why on earth are there no keyboard shortcuts by default? Such an impediment to usability (not to mention accessibility - what if you can't use a mouse?)

Answer (score 34):

If anyone is wondering how to do this with GTK3 - simply open `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and add the following:

```
@binding-set MyTreeViewBinding
{
    bind "Left"     { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,0,0) };
    bind "Right"    { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,1,0) };
}

GtkTreeView
{
  gtk-key-bindings: MyTreeViewBinding;
}
```

Comment: This is very relevant as Eclipse recently moved to GTK 3 - while all 4.x releases can use GTK 3 by setting an environment variables, Mars has moved to GTK 3 by default.

Comment: +1000! Thank you! This is exactly what needs to be done and what I have been looking for for quite a while. You have made my life a whole lot easier!!!! (Linux Mint 17.2, Eclipse 4.5, STS 3.7.0)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32529393/306047, IMHO it is useful to bind the "Left" key to "select-cursor-parent" as well.

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 and worked smoothly. Thanks :)

Comment: Have just created this gtk.css under ~/.config/gtk-3.0/ and it works like a charm on CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611
Now am able to navigate using Keyboard arrows on Eclipse!!

Comment: This worked fine for me for a while, but now on Ubuntu 17.04 with GTK+ 3.22 it stopped working.  Any additional hints will be appreciated.

Comment: See my answer for GTK 3.2+ update https://stackoverflow.com/a/55537016/800413

Answer (score 12):

The answer provided by Andrew is correct. Please note that in newer versions of Ubuntu there is no ~/.gtkrc-2.0 file, so you can either create it or you can edit the gtkrc of your current theme, which is stored in

/usr/share/themes/your_theme/gtk-2.0/gtkrc

Comment: Since I recently switched to Linux Mint (Cinnamon) I tried to figure out how to restore this useful trick, since the your_theme folder does not contain any gtk* file.

The answer is this file:

/usr/share/themes/Default/gtk-2.0-key/gtkrc

Answer (score 5):

I tried to use [the answer from @Andrew Lazarev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32529393/800413). However due to a non backward compatible change on GTK3.20 (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=766166) the bindings have to be slightly adapted:

```
@binding-set MyTreeViewBinding
{
   bind "Left"     { "select-cursor-parent" ()
                  "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,0,0) };
   bind "Right"    { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,1,0) };
}

treeview
{
   -gtk-key-bindings: MyTreeViewBinding;
}
```

Note the `-` before `gtk-key-bindings` and the `GtkTreeView` renamed to `treeview`.

Comment: Is there a way to add flow control or conditions? As you see, when you hit left arrow, it navigates to the parent and applies collapse. What a user usually wants is: *if current element is collapsable and is expanded: collapse, else if current element no collapsable or is collapsed: navigate to parent.* How would you go about that?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. That finally worked for me with Eclipse 2021-09 with slightly different mapping:
```{
bind "<Alt>Up"  { "select-cursor-parent" ()};
bind "Left"     { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,0,0) };
bind "Right"    { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,1,0) };
}```

Answer (score 2):

The navigation of Tree widget is controlled by underlaying widget toolkit - GTK. SWT/Eclipse has no control over it.
If any such configuration is required for changing the short-cut, then it has to be made from the GTK side itself.

Comment: Thanks That makes sense. In Nautilus however, I can expand nodes with the arrow keys without shift. I looked in System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts but don't see anything about this shortcut there.

Comment: The reason seems to be that in GTK a TreeView can have multiple columns, and left/right move between columns so they cannot be used to expand/collapse the node: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-devel-list/2004-March/msg00223.html (and yes, that's a very old mail)

Answer (score 1):

Basing on [YMomb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55537016/1948151) answer I ended up with config bellow (`~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`). Works well with Eclipse 2021-09.

```
@binding-set MyTreeViewBinding
{
    bind "<Ctrl>Left" { "select-cursor-parent" ()
                   "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,0,0) };
    bind "Left"     { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,0,0) };
    bind "Right"    { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,1,0) };
}

treeview
{
  -gtk-key-bindings: MyTreeViewBinding;
}
```