# Expand tree nodes with right and left arrow keys on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a problem with the right and left keys on Eclipse. Until now, I have used Eclipse on Windows platform and it lets me open the child elements when I clicked on the right arrow key and it closed the child elements with the left arrow key. I switched to the Ubuntu and these keys do not open/close the child elements anymore on Eclipse.

This is the default case:

[image]

and then, when I clicked on right arrow key, it opened the child elements like that;

After clicking on right arrow key:

[image]

Even if I looked the keys in the settings, I could not find the shortcut entry for this behaviour in the settings of the Eclipse.

Comment: This is probably a function of the native control that Eclipse uses for the Tree and can't be changed in Eclipse.

Comment: This is not really a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747264) since this is not about the package explorer and it is not about expanding nodes without the shift-key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know which shortcut entry in Eclipse but when you use the Eclipse on Ubuntu, you can get the same behaviour with shift + left/right arrow keys instead of onyl left/right arrow keys.

In order to change the behaviour on Ubuntu, please have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747264/is-it-possible-to-use-arrow-keys-alone-to-expand-tree-node-in-package-explorer-i/32529393#32529393) and the answer of @big data nerd should work on newer versions of Ubuntu (tested)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure this expands only *one* level of nodes, and not **all* nodes? I have a vague feeling Shift+Right expands all nodes on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Lii I have checked after your comment and it expands only the next level, not all nodes. I have ubuntu 16.04 installed on my laptop.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer's link. [The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55537016/1051589) on the same post solved my problem.